# Gather a split 2D array with MPI in C

Tags: c, performance, parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi

I need to adapt this part of a very long code to mpi in c.

```
for (i = 0; i < total; i++) {
   sum = A[next][0][0]*B[i][0] + A[next][0][1]*B[i][1] + A[next][0][2]*B[i][2];
   next++;
   while (next < last) {
      col = column[next];
      sum += A[next][0][0]*B[col][0] + A[next][0][1]*B[col][1] + A[next][0][2]*B[col][2];
      final[col][0] += A[next][0][0]*B[i][0] + A[next][1][0]*B[i][1] + A[next][2][0]*B[i][2];
      next++;
}
final[i][0] += sum;}
```

And I was thinking of code like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
   for (j = 0; j < total; j++) {
      check_thread[i][j] = false;
   }
}
part = total / num_threads;
for (i = thread_id * part; i < ((thread_id + 1) * part); i++) {
   sum = A[next][0][0]*B[i][0] + A[next][0][1]*B[i][1] + A[next][0][2]*B[i][2];
   next++;
   while (next < last) {
     col = column[next];
     sum += A[next][0][0]*B[col][0] + A[next][0][1]*B[col][1] + A[next][0][2]*B[col][2];
     if (!check_thread[thread_id][col]) {
        check_thread[thread_id][col] = true;
        temp[thread_id][col] = 0.0;
     }      
     temp[thread_id][col] += A[next][0][0]*B[i][0] + A[next][1][0]*B[i][1] + A[next][2][0]*B[i][2];
     next++;
   }
   if (!check_thread[thread_id][i]) {
      check_thread[thread_id][i] = true;
      temp[thread_id][i] = 0.0;
   }
 temp[thread_id][i] += sum;
}
*
for (i = 0; i < total; i++) {
   for (j = 0; j < num_threads; j++) {
     if (check_thread[j][i]) {
        final[i][0] += temp[j][i];
     }
   }
}
```

Then I need to gather all the temporary parts in one, I was thinking of `MPI_Allgather` and something like this just before the last two for (where *):

```
  MPI_Allgather(temp, (part*sizeof(double)), MPI_DOUBLE, temp, sizeof(**temp), MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

But I get an execution error, Is it possible to send and receive in the same variable?, if not, what could be the other solution in this case?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the MPI_Allgather with the wrong parameters:

```
 MPI_Allgather(temp, (part*sizeof(double)), MPI_DOUBLE, temp, sizeof(**temp), MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Instead you should have ([source](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.2/www3/MPI_Allgather.html)) :

> **MPI_Allgather**
>
> Gathers data from all tasks and distribute the combined data to all
> tasks
>
> Input Parameters 
> sendbuf starting address of send buffer (choice) 
> sendcount number of elements in send buffer (integer)
> sendtype data type of send buffer elements (handle)
> recvcount number of elements received from any process (integer)
> recvtype data type of receive buffer elements (handle)
> comm communicator (handle)

Your `sendcount` and `recvcount` arguments are both wrong, instead of (part*sizeof(double)) and sizeof(**temp) you should pass the number of elements from the matrix `temp` that will be gather by all processes involved.

The matrix can be gather in a single call if that matrix is continuously allocated in memory, if it was created as an array of pointers, then you will have to call `MPI_Allgather` for each row of the matrix, or use [MPI_Allgatherv](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.2/www3/MPI_Allgatherv.html) instead.

> Is it possible to send and receive in the same variable?

Yes, by using the [In-place Option](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v3.0/man3/MPI_Allgather.3.php#toc8)

> When the communicator is an intracommunicator, you can perform an
> all-gather operation in-place (the output buffer is used as the input
> buffer). **Use the variable MPI_IN_PLACE as the value of sendbuf.** In
> this case, sendcount and sendtype are ignored. The input data of each
> process is assumed to be in the area where that process would receive
> its own contribution to the receive buffer. Specifically, the outcome
> of a call to MPI_Allgather that used the in-place option is identical
> to the case in which all processes executed n calls to

> MPI_GATHER ( MPI_IN_PLACE, 0, MPI_DATATYPE_NULL, recvbuf,
> recvcount, recvtype, root, comm )